# how to find the area of shaded region from the plot using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

```
x = data
rank = np.arange(1,x.size+1)  # ranks = {1, 2, 3, ... 10}
median_rank = (rank - 0.3)/(rank.size + 0.4)
y = ln(-ln(1 - median_rank))


x_ideal = data
x_ideal.sort()
F = 1 - np.exp( -(x_ideal/10000)**100 )
y_ideal = ln(-ln(1 - F))

ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x_ideal, y_ideal)
plt.title("Weibull Probability Plot on Log Scale", weight="bold")
plt.xlabel('x (time)', weight="bold")
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Distribution Function', weight="bold")
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

this is the code for this plot. i need to find the area of grey color region